# Display a list of combination of the numbers with out refreshing page each time to get different combination

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently my code my shows 3 numbers at one time with different combinations.

Question Instead of refreshing page to get a new set of numbers from the array I would like to be able to show a list of combinations.

The code below prints out example a combination of the numbers below.

I have had a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php but unsure

```
$my_array = array('1', '2', '3');

for ($i = 0; $i <2; $i++) {

    $random = array_rand($my_array); # one random array element number

    $get_it = list($my_array[$random]; # get the number from the array

    echo $get_it;

    unset($my_array[$random]);
}
```

Wanted example output

- 123
- 321
- 213
- 132

Comment: If you want to get all unique combinations using array elements, you can check offered functions in answers [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73749/generate-every-unique-combination-using-all-elements-from-array) or [here](https://gist.github.com/fabiocicerchia/4556892). I am not sure do you want to use some timeout callback to get something else (like content) without refreshing page.

Comment: Thank you @Tpojka found what I wanted from your link.

Comment: Thanks for who ever voted down